NetSuite Saved Search - Removing <BR> for results
We use a NS saved search to feeds data including tracking numbers into our EDI system.
However, if there is more than 1 tracking number (e.g. multipackage shipment), NetSuite returns the tracking number with a line break tag between each:

TRACKING1<BR>TRACKING2<BR>TRACKING3

We need to remove the "<BR>" since they are not part of the tracking numbers and <> are invalid characters for EDI.
We've tried the replace function below, but it is yielding "ERROR: Invalid Expression"

REPLACE({trackingnumbers}, "<BR>"," ")

Appreciate any input - thanks!

The formula is a SQL expression.  You need to use single quotes (') rather than double quotes (") for string literals.
REPLACE({trackingnumbers}, '<BR>',' ')


:facepalm: So simple. Thank you!
